# Iterating over Jekyll posts from an external rake task

Tags: jekyll

I'm writing a Rake task to automatically update my Jekyll site, based on the response from an external API. For example, the API may return a list of posts and I would create files in the `_posts` directory for any new content.

Every post has an ID, and that's what I use to determine if it's been previously published or not.

My question: how can I access the `site` object from within my Rake task (i.e. external to the running Jekyll environment) in order to access the `id` frontmatter in each post's header?

**Note:** I'd like to avoid parsing files myself, and would really like to use Jekyll to do that, if possible.

EDIT: Pretty sure this would involve `require Jekyll::...` but I'm unsure what needs to be included to allow access to the `site` variable